# Can I make a "layer"

Tags: android, view

Is there any way to create a view above all the others,so when this view is visible, I cannot interact with other views except this one. Sounds like a lock screen.And yeah,that's what I really want to achieve. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please stop writing "Android:" at the start of all your question titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a RelativeLayout which fills parent both in width and height. Let this layout have a child view which could be any view.

Put the view on top and set a onTouchlistener.

```
 view.bringToFront();
 view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                return true;
            }

        });
```

That is, have a touch listener that takes all touch events and consumes them (return true).

Answer (score 0):

Use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and ViewGroup.bringChildToFront for the View you want to be above all others.

When adding element to [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) set layout_height and layout_width to 'match_parent'

Comment: but i still can interact with the contents below the front view

Comment: take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable(boolean)) I guess you should disable events for all children of your Layout

Comment: You can also use [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) with custom layout.